# How to create a query on an existing table and build a table(view) with bool data using a logic condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, conditional-statements, pivot-table

What I have is an MS-SQL database that I use to store data/info coming from equipment that is mounted in some vehicles (1-3 equipments per vehicle).

For the moment, there is a table in the database named `Communication` - a big table used to store every information from the equipments when they connect to the TCP-server. Records are added one after another (only INSERTS here).

The table looks like this:

[image]

What I need is a `SQL` query (command/statement) to create a table(view) for a so-called "Weekly Communication Status", where I can see **if/how the vehicles have communicated in the last 7 days**... something like the table below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the above, given, you know there will only be 7 date columns in the output you can do a manual pivot rather than using the PIVOT operator.

[See SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41c53/8)

```
select VehicleNumber, 
      CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [7 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-6,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [6 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-5,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [5 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-4,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [4 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-3,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [3 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-2,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [2 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [1 Days Ago]
      ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DateTimeCommunication, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' Else 'NO' END AS [0 Days Ago]
from Communications
GROUP BY VehicleNumber
```

Comment: @groenhen you will notice the Sum function wrapping each line. Because we are grouping the data by vehicle number I.E. Each row shows a single vehicle, all other data displayed is aggregated. Aggregation in this case is taking the rows for a single vehicle and squishing them together. The sum function is then effectively counting every time we have a matching date. So at the end of the line we then say, if this count is > 0 then 'Yes' . So, as this is using a group by, we need to use an aggregate function and hence we need to do all the extra stuff. Easier to read in my opinion. ok ?

Comment: Thanks sarin. I just figured out immediately after asking that question, probably I was too tired as I didn't noticed SUM at the first read... That why I delete the comment. But your answer is highly welcome, as it is always good to have a confirmation :)

Comment: Postponed for tomorrow as my car stubbornly refused to start this morning. Fixed now so tomorrow I'll be back on rails:) Hey - off topic, but very useful - now I know how to change the car's fuel filter without having to pray for it to start after the replacement! ;)

Comment: Forgot to say: Thanks for SQL Fiddle! Didnt know such thing exists... nice!

Comment: Yes it works! There's still one thing I wasnt able to do: How can I change "0 days ago" into "25-06-15", "1 days ago" into "24-06-15"... etc? I searched for solutions with google but none worked... :(

Comment: 2 options. 1) The easier. You don't change them and then in your User Interface that is displaying the report you replace the column headers for the appropriate dates using whatever functions are available. 2) Use Dynamic SQL to replace the column headers. If you want me to solve that one (which isn't too difficult), Create a new question, linking to this one with the query in and will be happy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dynamic `PIVOT` approach.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(equipmentID int, vehicleNumber int, DateTimeCommunication datetime)

INSERT INTO #temp(equipmentID, vehicleNumber, DateTimeCommunication)
VALUES  (1,100,GETDATE()),
        (2,110,GETDATE()),
        (3,120,GETDATE()),
        (5,140,GETDATE()),
        (1,100,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE())),
        (3,120,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE())),
        (4,130,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE())),
        (5,140,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE()))

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @columns nvarchar(max), @columnsSelect nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + N',['+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),dateCom)+N']',N'['+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),dateCom)+N']')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(date, DateTimeCommunication) as dateCom
    FROM #temp
) as allDates
ORDER BY dateCom

SELECT @columnsSelect = COALESCE(@columnsSelect + N',ISNULL(['+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),dateCom)+N'],N''NO'') as '''+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),dateCom)+'''',
                                    N'ISNULL(['+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),dateCom)+N'],N''NO'') as '''+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),dateCom)+'''')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(date, DateTimeCommunication) as dateCom
    FROM #temp
) as allDates
ORDER BY dateCom

SET @sql = N'SELECT pvt.vehicleNumber, '+@columnsSelect+'
FROM (
    SELECT t.equipmentID, t.vehicleNumber, CONVERT(date,DateTimeCommunication) as dateCom,
        CASE WHEN t.DateTimeCommunication BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
            THEN N''YES''
            ELSE N''NO''
        END as communicated
    FROM #temp t
) as dat
PIVOT(
    MAX(communicated)
    FOR dateCom IN('+@columns+')
) as pvt'
PRINT(@sql)
EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

If you don't need it dynamic or just for a specified date range, just simplify it again to this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(equipmentID int, vehicleNumber int, DateTimeCommunication datetime)

INSERT INTO #temp(equipmentID, vehicleNumber, DateTimeCommunication)
VALUES  (1,100,GETDATE()),
        (2,110,GETDATE()),
        (3,120,GETDATE()),
        (5,140,GETDATE()),
        (1,100,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE())),
        (3,120,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE())),
        (4,130,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE())),
        (5,140,DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE()))

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.equipmentID, t.vehicleNumber, CONVERT(date,DateTimeCommunication) as dateCom,
        CASE WHEN t.DateTimeCommunication BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
            THEN N'YES'
            ELSE N'NO'
        END as communicated
    FROM #temp t
) as dat
PIVOT(
    MAX(communicated)
    FOR dateCom IN([2015-06-23]) --needs to be changed on different date!
) as pvt

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: I will definitely try the 2nd approach tomorrow. Now/Here I dont have an SQL server, so... :)  Many thanks, jope it'll work :)

Comment: No problem. Just tell me if it won't be the thing you're looking for. But all worked on my machine.